# Jasper ireport query design

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to draw a chart in Jasper iReport that can sum the results based on user selection.
Let's say I have the fruits table:

```
id (pk)       town          bananas          orange          cherry 
1            boston           5                 0              11              
2            paris            100               18             12              
3            bucharest        10                3              9
4            barcelona        9                 4              12
```

From a Jasper web server input control with an ireport parameter associated (java.util.collection) user will select the fruit/fruits.

I need to sum all the fruits selected by the user and plot the chart.

For example, when then user selects both 'bananas'  and 'oranges' the result would be

```
              town          result  
1            boston           5 
2            paris            118 
3            bucharest        13 
4            barcelona        13
```

The problem is:

I can't do 
`select sum(bananas,orange) as result from fruits group by town`.

mysql sum function doesn't work this way, but this is the way jasper input control return the user selection back to report query.

I've tried `SELECT (SELECT REPLACE('bananas,orange', ',', '+')) as result from fruits group by town`, but MySQL doesn't recognize the replace statement as column name.
I get this:

```
              town          result  
1            boston           bananas+orange 
2            paris            bananas+orange
3            bucharest        bananas+orange
4            barcelona        bananas+orange
```

also, `SELECT sum(SELECT REPLACE('bananas,orange', ',', '+')) as result from fruits group by town`
will return 0 as result

Any idea? Maybe this can be done from ireport..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could dynamically create the following query (using a stored procedure) based on the input parameters that your user specifies. Then the stored procedure would become your data source within the JRXML.

```
select id, town, sum(bananas) + sum(oranges) as result from fruits group by town
```

I now think that this is messy.

An alternative would be to re-factor the FRUIT_SALES table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE "SEEDY_FOODS"."FRUIT_SALES"
  (
    "ID"            NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "TOWN"          VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "FRUIT_TYPE_ID" NUMBER,
    "QTY_SOLD"      NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FRUIT_SALES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") 
  )
```

Sample data

```
FRUIT_SALES
 ID TOWN    FRUIT_TYPE_ID  SALES
 1  boston  1              5
 2  boston  2              0
 3  boston  3              11
 4  paris   1              100
 5  paris   2              18
 6  paris   3              12
```

Then have a reference table such as.

```
CREATE TABLE "SEEDY_FOODS"."FRUIT_TYPES"
  (
    "ID"   NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  )
```

Sample data

```
FRUIT_TYPE
 ID NAME
 1  bananas
 2  orange
 3  cherry
```

*The above DDL SQL was created for Oracle using SQL Developer. You will need to verify this syntax on MySQL*

Now the target query to act as a data source for your Jasper Report becomes

```
select town, sum(qty_sold)
from fruit_sales
where $X{IN,FRUIT_TYPE_ID,COUNTED_FRUIT_TYPES}
group by town
```

Here we make us of the JasperReports feature `$X{IN,<column>,<PARAMETER>}` to only select those rows which meet the criteria of fruit specified in the the parameter `$P{COUNTED_FRUIT_TYPES}` which is of type `java.util.Collection`

Here's the start of the JXRML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
              name="FruitSalesByTown" 
              language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" 
              leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" 
              uuid="9cc45ae0-15a8-4f13-8e02-b0a4379f7019">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
 :
 :
snip style tags 
 :
 :
    <parameter name="COUNTED_FRUIT_TYPES" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select town, sum(qty_sold)
from fruit_sales
where $X{IN,FRUIT_TYPE_ID,COUNTED_FRUIT_TYPES}
group by town]]>
    </queryString>
```

(ref. Page 80 of the Jasper Reports Ultimate Guide)

Comment: Thank yuo. this can be done, but I need to sum only some fruits. You say is it possible to do this from jxrml?